# why am I getting an empty list while scraping website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, nlp

```
url = 'https://inshorts.com/en/read/technology'
news_data = []
news_category = url.split('/')[-1]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if data.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')

    headlines = soup.find('div', class_=['news-card-title', 'news-right-box'])
    articles = soup.find('div', class_=['news-card-content', 'news-right-box'])

    if headlines and articles and len(headlines) == len(articles):
        news_articles = [
            {
                'news_headline': headline.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'headline'}).string,
                'news_article': article.find_all('div', attrs={'itemprop': 'articleBody'}).string,
                'news_category': news_category
            }
            for headline, article in zip(headlines, articles)
        ]
        news_data.extend(news_articles)

print(news_data)
```

The code above tries to scrape the data from inshorts website and divide it into 3 categories namely `news_headline`,`news_article` and `news_category`

Comment: have you checked manually whether such combinations of classes and divs are actually present on the page?

Answer (score 3):

You get the empty list because of your condition, it fails because `headlines / articles` are `None`, what means not found by your selector.

Try to select your elements more specific, avoid zipping several lists and get information in one go - I used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here but you can also use `find() / find_all()`.

Select all article elements, iterate them and pick information for each:

```
...
if data.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)

    for article in soup.select('[itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"]'):
        news_data.append(
            {
                'news_headline': article.select_one('[itemprop="headline"]').get_text(),
                'news_article': article.select_one('[itemprop="articleBody"]').get_text(),
                'news_category': news_category
            }
        )

print(news_data)
```

Comment: but only one news headline and corresponding to that only one news article is getting repeated a number of times. not getting different news headlines available in the website.

Comment: @VighneshBhat that's because @HedgeHog used the wrong variable. Instead of `soup.select_one` just call `article.select_one`. His code works fine, I tested it locally. Now the edit is live

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache Thank you for your attention and correction, in fact it is the `article` that should be referenced, something crept in during editing. Many thanks

Comment: @VighneshBhat feel free to accept this answer as solution if it actually helped!